# Moving file on WEBDAV server returns 404 even though file exists

Tags: apache, http, https, webdav, cadaver

I can't move specific files on our server via webdav forth and back and can't find the source of the issue. Some examples:

Works: `README.md` -> `README1.md` -> `README.md`

Works: `db.xml.gz` -> `db.xml.bla` -> `db.xml.gz`

Doesn't work: `db.xml.gz` -> `db.xml.gz.lock` -> `db.xml.gz` (results in `404`)

Tried it with [cadaver](http://www.webdav.org/cadaver/):

```
dav:/webdav/User/> ls
Listing collection `/webdav/User/': succeeded.
        .htaccess                            117  Jun  6  2018
        db.xml.gz                            635  Feb  7 21:36
dav:/webdav/User/> mv db.xml.gz db.xml.gz.lock
Moving `/webdav/User/db.xml.gz' to `/webdav/User/db.xml.gz.lock':  succeeded.
dav:/webdav/User/> mv db.xml.gz.lock db.xml.gz
Moving `/webdav/User/db.xml.gz.lock' to `/webdav/User/db.xml.gz':  failed:
404 Not Found
dav:/webdav/User/> ls
Listing collection `/webdav/User/': succeeded.
        .htaccess                            117  Jun  6  2018
        db.xml.gz.lock                       635  Feb  7 21:36
dav:/webdav/User/> mv db.xml.gz.lock db.xml
Moving `/webdav/User/db.xml.gz.lock' to `/webdav/User/db.xml':  failed:
404 Not Found
dav:/webdav/User/> mv db.xml.gz.lock db.bla
Moving `/webdav/User/db.xml.gz.lock' to `/webdav/User/db.bla':  succeeded.
dav:/webdav/User/> mv db.bla db.blubb
Moving `/webdav/User/db.bla' to `/webdav/User/db.blubb':  succeeded.
dav:/webdav/User/> mv db.blubb db.bla
Moving `/webdav/User/db.blubb' to `/webdav/User/db.bla':  succeeded.
```

It seems to fail if the source is the same as the target plus additional file endings. I read that some windows servers skip the file ending which causes issues, but this is a Linux machine. 
Any ideas highly appreciated!

Comment: Is your host machine a Windows machine? (not the server on which you're running these commands.) If so maybe it the Windows file extension problem you mentioned is getting you?

Comment: No, the host machine is Linux as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this bug report](https://grokbase.com/t/apache/bugs/101kdn2xkq/do-not-reply-bug-48576-new-move-or-copy-in-webdav-fails-with-404-when-file-extension-is-changed) with the solution: Disabling MultiViews in the apache host configuration fixed the issue. MultiViews was preventing me basically from renaming some file extensions.